# Как сохранить аудиозаписи в кеш Android?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Пишу плеер под андроид, не могу понять, как правильно сохранять аудиозаписи в кеш системы и как их оттуда удалять.

Comment: «как правильно сохранять аудиозаписи в кеш системы и как их оттуда удалять» – ровно также, как и любой другой файл. Вы знаете, как можно сохранить, например, текстовый файл на диске? А как удалить его?

Comment: Все через буфер? Я просто не работал с такими файлами ещё.

Comment: Смотря что Вы подразумеваете под словом «буфер».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу уже второй вопрос по этой теме от тебя. Насчет кеширования аудиозаписей в VK я не знаю, но думаю тебе поможет в разработке мой [репозиторий](https://github.com/KostyaBakay/KBMP)  с простым плеером на основе vk.com и last.fm.